# Java Serialization: InvalidPathException : Illegal char <:> at index 13: 2021-03-31T18:25:56.746646500Z.tmp

Tags: java, serialization, path

How can I get rid of this Exception? I'm trying to create a Path for a file whose name will be a timestamp, and I'm doing this by adding automatically his name with the help of the second parameter in the .format method which will remplace the {0}, in the temp.file property.

```
In the config.properties file:
 temp.file={0}.tmp


In the productManger.java

public class productManager {

Path tempFolder= Path.of("/Users/Joe/temp");
ResourceBundle config = ResourceBundle.getBundle("packageone.config");




Path tempfile = tempFolder.resolve(MessageFormat.format(config.getString("temp.file"), Instant.now()));

 try {

            if(Files.notExists(tempFolder)){
                Files.createDirectory(tempFolder);
            }

try ( ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(tempfile, StandardOpenOption.CREATE))) {

                out.writeObject(new Object[1]);
              
            }

     }catch (IOException io){
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error dumping data " + io.getMessage());
           io.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Have a problem with Windows(NTFS) who don't accept some characters for files names
(The following reserved characters:
< (less than)

> (greater than)
> : (colon)
> " (double quote)
> / (forward slash)
> \ (backslash)
> | (vertical bar or pipe)
> ? (question mark)

- (asterisk)

Solution: Instant.now().toString().replaceAll(":"," ")